# Redirection problems

Tags: wp-redirect

Please help me to overcome the redirection issue.

I need to work on subdomain rather than working on the main domain but here both domain is different.

What I did is - copied all (website.com) files to another subdomain(demo.websiteA.com) and changed the database name as per wp-config.php file.

But whenever I try to open demo.websiteA.com it redirects to website.com

Please help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you also change your sites url to match the new domain/subdomain?

Answer (score 2):

If you can log in to **phpmyadmin**, you can check the `wp-options` table in the database to check the value below, if it's `website.com`, you must edit two line below is `demo.websiteA.com`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, you need to change all references of old site URLs to new site URLs. Try this plugin's 'Find & Replace' option - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/ and don't forgot to delete cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the old Wordpress URL with these SQL Queries:

```
# Options
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'website.com', 'demo.websiteA.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

# Posts & Postmeta
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'website.com', 'demo.websiteA.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'website.com','demo.websiteA.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'website.com','demo.websiteA.com');

# Usermeta
UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'website.com','demo.websiteA.com');

# Links
UPDATE wp_links SET link_url = replace(link_url, 'website.com','demo.websiteA.com');

# Comments
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = replace(comment_content , 'website.com','demo.websiteA.com');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_author_url = replace(comment_author_url, 'website.com','demo.websiteA.com');
```

Replace: "website.com" with your Old URL

Replace: "demo.websiteA.com" with your New URL

Comment: What happens if you change a serialized object?